# Модальное popup window в Android

Tags: android, gui

Есть задача сделать всплывающее окно особого дизайна. Дизайн я сделал, класс для Popup Windows создал. Теперь нужно чтобы это окно было модальным, т.е. имело прозрачный фон, за котором было бы видно Activity.

Не могу найти как это можно сделать.

Пробовал создать окно с родительским слоем, которое, будучи растянуто на весь экран, выполняло бы задачу модального фона. свойство background выставил как цвет с прозрачностью. Однако, в результате у меня не получилось прозрачного модального окна. Цвет фона был просто светлее и за ним ничего небыло видно. как быть?

```
<GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/tracker_control_modal"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/master_blue_dark_transparent"
        android:columnCount="1"
        android:rowCount="1"
        >

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tracker_control_root"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/master_white"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

        <GridLayout
                style="@style/Style_TrackerControl_Item"
                android:id="@+id/tracker_control_item_preference">

            <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="close"
                    android:id="@+id/close_button"/>
        </GridLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Пробовали задать цвет в коде а не в XML , или указать цвет в XML @android:color/transparent

Answer (score 1):

Для прозрачности элементов используйте альфа канал:

```
android:alpha="0.5" // - 50%
android:alpha="1" // - 100% (непрозрачный)
```

или программно:

```
textView.getBackground().setAlpha(80);
```

Если вы хотите сменить альфа-канал для определенного цвета, воспользуйтесь этой hex таблицей прозрачности:

```
100% — FF
99% — FC
98% — FA
97% — F7
96% — F5
95% — F2
94% — F0
93% — ED
92% — EB
91% — E8
90% — E6
89% — E3
88% — E0
87% — DE
86% — DB
85% — D9
84% — D6
83% — D4
82% — D1
81% — CF
80% — CC
79% — C9
78% — C7
77% — C4
76% — C2
75% — BF
74% — BD
73% — BA
72% — B8
71% — B5
70% — B3
69% — B0
68% — AD
67% — AB
66% — A8
65% — A6
64% — A3
63% — A1
62% — 9E
61% — 9C
60% — 99
59% — 96
58% — 94
57% — 91
56% — 8F
55% — 8C
54% — 8A
53% — 87
52% — 85
51% — 82
50% — 80
49% — 7D
48% — 7A
47% — 78
46% — 75
45% — 73
44% — 70
43% — 6E
42% — 6B
41% — 69
40% — 66
39% — 63
38% — 61
37% — 5E
36% — 5C
35% — 59
34% — 57
33% — 54
32% — 52
31% — 4F
30% — 4D
29% — 4A
28% — 47
27% — 45
26% — 42
25% — 40
24% — 3D
23% — 3B
22% — 38
21% — 36
20% — 33
19% — 30
18% — 2E
17% — 2B
16% — 29
15% — 26
14% — 24
13% — 21
12% — 1F
11% — 1C
10% — 1A
9% — 17
8% — 14
7% — 12
6% — 0F
5% — 0D
4% — 0A
3% — 08
2% — 05
1% — 03
0% — 00
```

Пример: `android:background="#80FFFFFF"` // прозрачен на 50%

Comment: Если задать  android:alpha="0.5" то  это сделает полупрозрачным весь слой. т.е. и фон и само окно. Это не то что мне нужно.

Я еще раз попробовал через XML указать цвет с прозрачностью и в этот раз у меня получилось. Не знаю почему в первый раз не получалось. Поэтому проблема решена

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите документацию на [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html), это то, что вам нужно.

Вот небольшой tutorial: http://javatechig.com/android/android-dialog-fragment-example